# How to binding a property of property to a DataGridColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid

I'm creating my system using Entity Framework, I had binding the object property to a `DataGrid`, every field showed data, but just only a property `Fornecedor`, is a other class, can not show in the first time, it just will show when I open the New Register window and close, I don't know why it does this, because I use same method for show list in the constructor and NewRegister.Closed, fallow my class

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Linha { get; set; }
    public int Comprimento { get; set; }
    public int Largura { get; set; }
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    public string CorPe { get; set; }
    public int Gaveta { get; set; }
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }   // <- Fornecedor is other class
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
    public int Estoque { get; set; }
    public float ValorCompra { get; set; }
    public float ValorVenda { get; set; }
}
```

Fornecedor class here:

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string Email1 { get; set; }
    public string Email2 { get; set; }
    public string Email3 { get; set; }
    public string Telefone1 { get; set; }
    public string Telefone2 { get; set; }
    public string Telefone3 { get; set; }
}
```

So, I had set `DataContext` for my Window and set `Binding` for `DataGridTextColumns`

```
public PageMesa()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ShowList();
}

private void ShowList()
{
    listMesa.ItemsSource = db.Mesas.ToList();
}

private void NewCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MesaEditar NewRegister = new MesaEditar();
    NewRegister.Closed += (s, arg) => { ShowList(); };
    NewRegister.ShowDialog();
}
```

My DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="listMesa" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="1*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codigo" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Width="2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Linha" Binding="{Binding Linha}" Width="2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comprimento" Binding="{Binding Comprimento}" Width="3*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Largura" Binding="{Binding Largura}" Width="3*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cor" Width="2*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Cor}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cor do pé" Binding="{Binding CorPe}" Width="4*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gaveta" Binding="{Binding Gaveta}" Width="2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fornecedor" Binding="{Binding Fornecedor.Nome}" Width="4*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Estoque" Binding="{Binding Estoque}" Width="2*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor da compra" Binding="{Binding ValorCompra, StringFormat=R$0.00}" Width="4*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor da venda" Binding="{Binding ValorVenda, StringFormat=R$0.00}" Width="4*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Why does this happen?
Sorry for my bad expression, I don't know how to express this problem, please, ask me for every question

Comment: it's imposible to understand what the problem is , 
why have you not provided your datagrid and an example of the places you use the classes above Forecender and Produto .

Comment: If you want a property of a property you have to give the fully qualified name: `Key="Fornecedor.Nome"` for example. Just repeat this for all the properties you want to show. Can you show your XAML.

Comment: Are you sure `Fornecedor` is not null?

Comment: Sorry, I had forget post my DataGrid